# Javascript: What is the relationship between property descriptors and built-in property attributes

Tags: javascript

[According to this article](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/#property_attributes) the following builtin property attributes determine an objects writability characteristics: `ReadOnly, DontEnum, DontDelete and Internal.`.

I also read about [property descriptors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) determining an objects writability characteristics. A few notable ones are: `enumerable, writable, configurable`.

What is the relationship between these two concepts? They seem very similar, but I can't find any content which regards them as such.

Comment: I don't see anything about `writable` and `configurable` on the second page you linked to. Are you sure you used the right link?

Comment: One sec, i'll check now

Comment: I corrected it with the proper link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **8.6.1 Property Attributes** section from different docs. ECMAScript 5.1 is actual specification of Javascript.

[ECMAScript 3](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf) Object Model (inner, for browser engine usage)

- ReadOnly
- DontEnum
- DontDelete
- Internal

[ECMAScript 5.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) Object Model (enable set/get in javascript):

- [[Enumerable]]
- [[Configurable]]
- [[Writable]]
- [[Value]]